# No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to use the DotNetOpenAuth library to login programmatically from an aspx page. To start with, I'd like to just be able to login using a 3rd party openid provider like myopenid.

My website is an ASP .NET 4 web forms site hosted in IIS 7.5 hosted at port 9980. This port is open (inbound and outbound) in the computer's firewall.

I'm trying to use the OpenIdLogin login control but I keep getting a `ProtocolException` saying "No OpenID endpoint found"

I've already added this to `web.config/system.net`

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
     <proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Here's the funny part, the samples themselves are working fine. Any ideas?

-Thanks!

Comment: Well, I found the problem. It is an issue with the corporate firewall/proxy blocking outbound connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. It is an issue with the corporate firewall/proxy blocking outbound connections.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. What port number needs to be opened? And on which server (the one making the request, or the one receiving the request)?

Answer (score 1):

[Turn on logging](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs) and see what it says.  It often gives much more detail about why no endpoints were found.

Comment: I added logging. Did nothing but give me the errors that I already have. Just logged exceptions.

Comment: Did you set the verbosity to high?

Comment: This link for "Turn on logging" is dead, please update.  Also, logging for me gave same message, "No OpenId endpoint found"